# how to set up SPI communication between a STM32F746ZG and a MCP2515

Tags: spi, microchip, hal-library, stm32f7

I am trying to communicate my STM32F746ZG microcontroller with a MCP2515 and am having a problem where I don't believe the MCP2515 is receiving anything I have sent via SPI.

The reason I have come to this conclusion is because I have checked that my SPI code from the STM sends correctly through an oscilloscope (which it does), then following that check, I have tried to see if what I have written into the CNF1 register can be read back, which it doesn't (for example, if I set the CNF1 register to 00000100 or 0x04, the value that is read back is 0x00).

I was wondering if anyone has worked on a project like this and if they had any ideas on how I could fix this. (p.s. I am using HAL-Library)

mcp2515.c

```
/*
 * STM32F7xx_MCP2515.c
 * Library for Microchip MCP2515 CAN Controller
 *
 *  Created on: Jun 28, 2016
 *      Author: Nicholas Lloyd
 */

#include "MCP2515.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_spi.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_rcc_ex.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_flash_ex.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_it.h"
#include <stddef.h>

/*Private Define */
SPI_HandleTypeDef SPI_Structure;

// Constructor defining which pins to use for CS and INT

/* Global variables */
uint8_t SPI_BUFFER_TX1;
uint8_t SPI_BUFFER_TX2[2];
uint8_t SPI_BUFFER_TX3[3];
uint8_t SPI_BUFFER_TX4[4];
uint8_t SPI_BUFFER_RX2[2];
uint8_t SPI_BUFFER_RX3[3];
uint8_t SPI_NULL = 0x00;
uint8_t SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE[4];

void MCP2515_GPIO_Configuration(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    /* GPIO Clock Enables */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* Configuring Chip Select Pin */
    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode         = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pull         = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Speed        = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin          = SPI1_CS_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI1_CS_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    /* Setting the chip select to high so data can not be sent */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    /* SPI Clock Enable */
    __HAL_RCC_SPI1_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* GPIO Clock Enables */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* GeneralSPI GPIO Configuration */
    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode         = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pull         = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Speed        = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Alternate    = SPI1_AF;
    /* SPI SCK Pin Configuration */
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin          = SPI1_SCK_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI1_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    /* SPI MISO Pin Configuration */
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin          = SPI1_MISO_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI1_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    /* SPI MOSI Pin Configuration */
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin          =  SPI1_MOSI_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI1_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    /* GPIO Clock Enables */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* Configuring LED1, LED2, LED3 */
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin          = USER_LED_BLUE;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode         = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pull         = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Speed        = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(USER_LED_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    /* Check to see if LEDs run and if board functions */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(USER_LED_PORT, USER_LED_BLUE, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}

void MCP2515_SPI_Configuration(void)
{
    /* The SPI Handle for Channel 1 */
    SPI_Structure.Instance = SPI1;
    /* DeInitializes SPI1 */
    HAL_SPI_DeInit(&SPI_Structure);
    /* Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning */
    HAL_SPI_MspInit (&SPI_Structure);
    /* SPI configuration */
    SPI_Structure.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
    SPI_Structure.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
    SPI_Structure.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
    SPI_Structure.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
    SPI_Structure.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
    SPI_Structure.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
    SPI_Structure.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_64;
    SPI_Structure.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
    //SPI_Structure.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
    //SPI_Structure.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
    SPI_Structure.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
    /* Error Loop Init */
    HAL_SPI_Init(&SPI_Structure);
    __HAL_RCC_SYSCFG_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_SPI_ENABLE(&SPI_Structure);
}
/*
  Initialize MCP2515

  int CAN_Bus_Speed = transfer speed in kbps
  int Freq = MCP2515 oscillator frequency in MHz
  int SJW = Synchronization Jump Width Length bits - 1 to 4 (see data sheet)

  returns baud rate set

  Sending a bus speed of 0 kbps initiates AutoBaud and returns zero if no
  baud rate could be determined.  There must be two other active nodes on the bus!
*/
int MCP2515_Initialise(int baud, uint8_t Freq, uint8_t SJW) {
  if(SJW < 1) SJW = 1;
  if(SJW > 4) SJW = 4;
  if(baud > 0) {
    if(MCP2515_SubInitialise(baud, Freq, SJW, 0)) {
        return baud;
    }
  } else {
      int i=0;
      char interruptFlags = 0;
      for(i=5; i<1000; i=i+5) {
        if(MCP2515_SubInitialise(i, Freq, SJW, 1)) {
            // check for bus activity
            MCP2515_Single_Write(CANINTF,0);
            HAL_Delay(5); // need the bus to be communicating within this time frame
            if(MCP2515_Interrupt()) {
              // determine which interrupt flags have been set
              interruptFlags = MCP2515_Read(CANINTF);
              if(!(interruptFlags & MERRF)) {
                // to get here we must have received something without errors
                  MCP2515_Mode(MODE_NORMAL);
                  return i;
              }
            }
        }
      }
  }
  return 0;
}

int MCP2515_SubInitialise(int baud, uint8_t Freq, uint8_t SJW, uint8_t autoBaud) {

  // Reset MCP2515 which puts it in configuration mode
  MCP2515_Reset();

  // Calculate bit timing registers
  uint8_t BRP;
  float TQ;
  uint8_t BT;
  float tempBT;

  float NBT = 1.0 / (float)baud * 1000.0; // Nominal Bit Time us
  for(BRP=0;BRP<8;BRP++) {
    TQ = 2.0 * (float)(BRP + 1) / (float)Freq;
    tempBT = NBT / TQ;
      if(tempBT<=25) {
        BT = (int)tempBT;
        if(tempBT-BT==0) break;
      }
  }

  int SPT = (0.7 * BT); // Sample point
  uint8_t PRSEG = (SPT - 1) / 2;
  uint8_t PHSEG1 = SPT - PRSEG - 1;
  uint8_t PHSEG2 = BT - PHSEG1 - PRSEG - 1;

  // Programming requirements
  if(PRSEG + PHSEG1 < PHSEG2) return 0;
  if(PHSEG2 <= SJW) return 0;

  uint8_t BTLMODE = 1;
  uint8_t SAM = 0;

  // Set registers
  SJW = SJW - 1;
  SJW = SJW << 6;
  uint8_t CNF1_data = SJW;
  CNF1_data = CNF1_data | BRP;
  BTLMODE = BTLMODE << 7;
  uint8_t CNF2_data = BTLMODE;
  SAM = SAM << 6;
  CNF2_data = CNF2_data | SAM;
  PHSEG1 = PHSEG1 - 1;
  PHSEG1 = PHSEG1 << 3;
  CNF2_data = CNF2_data | PHSEG1;
  PRSEG = PRSEG - 1;
  CNF2_data = CNF2_data | PRSEG;
  uint8_t CNF3_data = 0x80;
  PHSEG2 = PHSEG2 - 1;
  CNF3_data = CNF3_data | PHSEG2;

  // Write to registers
  uint8_t correct_mode;
  correct_mode = MCP2515_Mode(MODE_CONFIG);
  if (correct_mode == 0) {
      while (1) {
      }
  }
  MCP2515_Single_Write(CNF1, CNF1_data);
  MCP2515_Single_Write(CNF2, CNF2_data);
  MCP2515_Single_Write(CNF3, CNF3_data);
  MCP2515_Single_Write(TXRTSCTRL,0);

  if(!autoBaud) {
    // Return to Normal mode
      if(!MCP2515_Mode(MODE_NORMAL)) return 0;
  } else {
    // Set to Listen Only mode
      if(!MCP2515_Mode(MODE_LISTEN)) return 0;
  }
  // Enable all interupts
  MCP2515_Single_Write(CANINTE,255);

  // Test that we can read back from the MCP2515 what we wrote to it
  uint8_t rtn = MCP2515_Read(CNF1);
  if (rtn==CNF1_data) {
      return 1;
  }
  else {
      return 0;
  }
}

void MCP2515_Reset(void)
{
    uint8_t check_status;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX1 = CAN_RESET_BASE;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    check_status = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_BUFFER_TX1, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    if (check_status != HAL_OK) {
        while (1) {
        }
    }
}

uint8_t MCP2515_Read(uint8_t address) {
    uint8_t data = 0x00;
    uint8_t check_status;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[0] = CAN_READ_BASE;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[1] = address;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[2] = SPI_NULL;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    check_status = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_BUFFER_TX3, &SPI_BUFFER_RX3, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    if (check_status != HAL_OK) {
        while (1) {
        }
    }
    data = SPI_BUFFER_RX3[2];
    return data;
}

void MCP2515_Read_Multiple(uint8_t address, uint8_t data[], uint8_t bytes) {
  // allows for sequential reading of registers starting at address - see data sheet
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  SPI_BUFFER_TX3[0] = CAN_READ_BASE;
  SPI_BUFFER_TX3[1] = address;
  SPI_BUFFER_TX3[2] = SPI_NULL;
  HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_BUFFER_TX3, &data, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE3,  SPI_TIMEOUT);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

uint8_t MCP2515_ReadBuffer(uint8_t buffer) {
  uint8_t data = 0x00;

  uint8_t address = CAN_READ_BUFFER_BASE | (buffer<<1);
  SPI_BUFFER_TX2[0] = address;
  SPI_BUFFER_TX2[1] = SPI_NULL;
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_BUFFER_TX2, &data, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE2, SPI_TIMEOUT);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  return data;
}

void MCP2515_Single_Write(uint8_t address, uint8_t data) {
    uint8_t check_status1;
//  uint8_t check_status2;
//  uint8_t check_status3;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[0] = CAN_WRITE_BASE;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[1] = address;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[2] = data;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    check_status1 = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_BUFFER_TX3, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE3, SPI_TIMEOUT);
//  check_status1 = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, CAN_WRITE, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
//  check_status2 = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &address, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
//  check_status3 = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &data, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    if (check_status1 != HAL_OK) {
        while (1) {
        }
    }
//  if (check_status2 != HAL_OK) {
//      while (1) {
//      }
//  }
//  if (check_status3 != HAL_OK) {
//      while (1) {
//      }
//  }
}

void MCP2515_SendBuffer(uint8_t buffers) {
  // buffers should be any combination of TXB0, TXB1, TXB2 ORed together, or TXB_ALL
    uint8_t address = CAN_RTS_BASE | buffers;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &address, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

void MCP2515_LoadBuffer(uint8_t buffer, uint8_t data) {
    uint8_t address = CAN_LOAD_BUFFER_BASE | buffer;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX2[0] = address;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX2[1] = data;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_BUFFER_TX2, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE2, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

uint8_t MCP2515_Status() {
    uint8_t data = 0x00;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[0] = CAN_STATUS_BASE;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[1] = SPI_NULL;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[2] = SPI_NULL;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, CAN_STATUS, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_NULL, &data, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_NULL, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    return data;
  /*
  bit 7 - CANINTF.TX2IF
  bit 6 - TXB2CNTRL.TXREQ
  bit 5 - CANINTF.TX1IF
  bit 4 - TXB1CNTRL.TXREQ
  bit 3 - CANINTF.TX0IF
  bit 2 - TXB0CNTRL.TXREQ
  bit 1 - CANINTFL.RX1IF
  bit 0 - CANINTF.RX0IF
  */
}

uint8_t MCP2515_RXStatus() {
    uint8_t data = 0x00;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[0] = CAN_RX_STATUS_BASE;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[1] = SPI_NULL;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX3[2] = SPI_NULL;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, CAN_RX_STATUS, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_NULL, &data, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_NULL, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    return data;
  /*
  bit 7 - CANINTF.RX1IF
  bit 6 - CANINTF.RX0IF
  bit 5 -
  bit 4 - RXBnSIDL.EIDE
  bit 3 - RXBnDLC.RTR
  bit 2 | 1 | 0 | Filter Match
  ------|---|---|-------------
      0 | 0 | 0 | RXF0
        0 | 0 | 1 | RXF1
        0 | 1 | 0 | RXF2
        0 | 1 | 1 | RXF3
        1 | 0 | 0 | RXF4
        1 | 0 | 1 | RXF5
        1 | 1 | 0 | RXF0 (rollover to RXB1)
        1 | 1 | 1 | RXF1 (rollover to RXB1)
  */
}

void MCP2515_BitModify(uint8_t address, uint8_t mask, uint8_t data) {
  // see data sheet for explanation
    uint8_t check_status;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX4[0] = CAN_BIT_MODIFY_BASE;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX4[1] = address;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX4[2] = mask;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX4[3] = data;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    check_status = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_BUFFER_TX4, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE4, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    while (check_status != 0) {
        while (1) {
        }
    }
}

uint8_t MCP2515_Interrupt(void) {
  if (__HAL_RCC_GET_IT(RCC_IT_HSERDY) == 1) return 1;
  else if (__HAL_RCC_GET_IT(RCC_IT_PLLRDY) == 1) return 1;
  else if (__HAL_RCC_GET_IT(RCC_IT_PLLI2SRDY) == 1) return 1;
  else if (__HAL_RCC_GET_IT(RCC_IT_CSS) == 1) return 1;
  else if (__HAL_SPI_GET_IT_SOURCE(&SPI_Structure, SPI_IT_TXE) == 1) return 1;
  else if (__HAL_SPI_GET_IT_SOURCE(&SPI_Structure, SPI_IT_RXNE) == 1) return 1;
  else if (__HAL_SPI_GET_IT_SOURCE(&SPI_Structure, SPI_IT_ERR) == 1) return 1;
  else return 0;
}

uint8_t MCP2515_Mode(uint8_t mode) {
  /*
  mode can be one of the following:
  MODE_CONFIG
  MODE_LISTEN
  MODE_LOOPBACK
  MODE_SLEEP
  MODE_NORMAL
  */

    MCP2515_BitModify(CANCTRL, 0xE0, mode);
    SPI_BUFFER_TX2[0] = CANSTAT_BASE;
    SPI_BUFFER_TX2[1] = SPI_NULL;
    uint8_t return_value = 0;
    uint8_t data;
    uint8_t check_status;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    check_status = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_BUFFER_TX2, &SPI_BUFFER_RX2, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE2, SPI_TIMEOUT);
//  HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, CANSTAT, &SPI_BLANK_RECEIVE, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT); // check mode has been set
//  HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_Structure, &SPI_NULL, &data, SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1, SPI_TIMEOUT); // check mode has been set
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_PORT, SPI1_CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    if (check_status != 0) {
        while (1) {
        }
    }
    data = SPI_BUFFER_RX2[1];
    if ((data & mode) == mode) return_value = 1;
    return return_value;
}

/*
 * return:
 *      1 - All transmit buffers clear
 *      2 - 1 and 2 buffers clear
 *      3 - 1 and 3 buffers clear
 *      4 - 1 buffer clear
 *      5 - 2 and 3 buffers clear
 *      6 - 2 buffer clear
 *      7 - 3 buffer clear
 *      0 - no buffers clear
 */
uint8_t MCP2515_Check_Buffers_Clear(uint8_t info) {
    uint8_t result = 0x00;
    if ((info & 0x0C) != 0x0C) {
        if ((info & 0x20) != 0x20) {
            if ((info & 0xC0) != 0xC0) {
                result = 0x01;
            } else {
                result = 0x02;
            }
        } else {
            if ((info & 0xC0) != 0xC0) {
                result = 0x03;
            } else {
                result = 0x04;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if ((info & 0x20) != 0x20) {
            if ((info & 0xC0) != 0xC0) {
                result = 0x05;
            } else {
                result = 0x06;
            }
        } else {
            if ((info & 0xC0) != 0xC0) {
                result = 0x07;
            } else {
                result = 0x00;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

uint16_t MCP2515_ReceivingMessage(uint8_t MCP2515_info, uint8_t MCP2515_RXdata)
{
    /* Buffer used for reception */
    uint8_t MCP2515_RxBuffer1 = 0;
    uint8_t MCP2515_RxBuffer2 = 0;
    uint16_t return_value = 0;

    /* Receiving a Message */
    if ((MCP2515_info & 0x01) == 0x01 || (MCP2515_info & 0x02) == 0x02) {                   // If Rx Buffer 1 and 2 are full
        if ((MCP2515_RXdata & 0xC0) == 0xC0) {                                  // if both Rx buffers hold messages
            MCP2515_RxBuffer1 = MCP2515_Read(RXB0D0);
            MCP2515_RxBuffer2 = MCP2515_Read(RXB1D0);
            if ((MCP2515_RXdata & 0x06) == 0x06) {                              // if messages are related (rollover)
                return_value = return_value | MCP2515_RxBuffer1;
                return_value = return_value << 8;
                return_value = return_value | MCP2515_RxBuffer2;
            }
        }
        else if ((MCP2515_RXdata & 0x40) == 0x40) {         // if Rx buffer 1 holds a message (buffer 2 holds a noise trip)
            return_value = MCP2515_Read(RXB0D0);
        }
        else if ((MCP2515_RXdata & 0x80) == 0x80) {         // if Rx buffer 2 holds a message (buffer 1 holds a noise trip)
            return_value = MCP2515_Read(RXB1D0);
        }
    }
    return return_value;
}

void MCP2515_SendingMessage(uint8_t MCP2515_info, uint16_t MCP2515_send_long_data, uint8_t MCP2515_send_data)
{
    /* Buffer used for transmission */
    uint8_t MCP2515_TxBuffer1;
    uint8_t MCP2515_TxBuffer2;

    uint8_t MCP2515_status_buffers;

    /* Sending a Message */
    if (MCP2515_send_data != 0 || MCP2515_send_long_data != 0) {                    // checks if a message is required to be sent
        MCP2515_status_buffers = MCP2515_Check_Buffers_Clear(MCP2515_info);                 // checks to see which Tx buffers are free
        while (MCP2515_status_buffers == 0){                                // if no buffers are free, loop until one is free
            MCP2515_status_buffers = MCP2515_Check_Buffers_Clear(MCP2515_info);
        }
        if (MCP2515_send_long_data != 0) {                                  // if a 16 bit message is required to be sent
            while ((MCP2515_status_buffers == 4) || MCP2515_status_buffers > 5) {   // loop until two buffers are free
                MCP2515_status_buffers = MCP2515_Check_Buffers_Clear(MCP2515_info);
            }
            MCP2515_TxBuffer1 = MCP2515_send_long_data;
            MCP2515_send_long_data = MCP2515_send_long_data >> 8;
            MCP2515_TxBuffer2 = MCP2515_send_long_data;
            if (0 < MCP2515_status_buffers && MCP2515_status_buffers < 3) {         // send through buffer 1 and 2
                MCP2515_Single_Write(TXB0D0, MCP2515_TxBuffer1);
                MCP2515_Single_Write(TXB1D0, MCP2515_TxBuffer2);
                MCP2515_SendBuffer(0x03);
                MCP2515_TxBuffer1 = 0x00;
                MCP2515_TxBuffer2 = 0x00;
            }
            else if (MCP2515_status_buffers == 3) {                         // send through buffer 1 and 3
                MCP2515_Single_Write(TXB0D0, MCP2515_TxBuffer1);
                MCP2515_Single_Write(TXB2D0, MCP2515_TxBuffer2);
                MCP2515_SendBuffer(0x05);
                MCP2515_TxBuffer1 = 0x00;
                MCP2515_TxBuffer2 = 0x00;
            }
            else if (MCP2515_status_buffers == 5) {                         // send through buffer 2 and 3
                MCP2515_Single_Write(TXB1D0, MCP2515_TxBuffer1);
                MCP2515_Single_Write(TXB2D0, MCP2515_TxBuffer2);
                MCP2515_SendBuffer(0x06);
                MCP2515_TxBuffer1 = 0x00;
                MCP2515_TxBuffer2 = 0x00;
            }
            MCP2515_send_long_data = 0x00;
        }
                                                                    // send a single message
        else if (MCP2515_send_data != 0) {                                  // send through buffer 1
            if (0 < MCP2515_status_buffers && MCP2515_status_buffers < 5) {
                MCP2515_Single_Write(TXB0D0, MCP2515_send_data);
                MCP2515_SendBuffer(0x01);
            }
            else if (4 < MCP2515_status_buffers && MCP2515_status_buffers < 7) {    // send through buffer 2
                MCP2515_Single_Write(TXB1D0, MCP2515_send_data);
                MCP2515_SendBuffer(0x02);
            }
            else if (MCP2515_status_buffers == 7) {                         // send through buffer 3
                MCP2515_Single_Write(TXB2D0, MCP2515_send_data);
                MCP2515_SendBuffer(0x04);
            }
            //MCP2515_send_data = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the scope show you is happening on MISO?  Do you get a non-zero value from reading any register?  What do you read if you do not drive the chip select, but instead pull up MISO to VDD with a small resistor?  Some chips require you to go through a sequence to unlock certain registers, but reading zero sounds as likely to be a configuration or electrical problem, so try some of these tests and see if you can get some non-zero values.

Comment: You should include the relevant code here (and scope output as Chris suggested). You haven't given us much to debug from.

Comment: Will try seeing if i get a non-zero value. I can't say I have tried doing any of those tests yet so will give it a go thanks Chris. And I will add the code now

Answer (score -1):

mcp2515.h

```
/*
 * STM32F7xx_MCP2515.h
 * Library for Microchip MCP2515 CAN Controller
 *
 *  Created on: Jun 28, 2016
 *      Author: Nicholas Lloyd
 *
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT(c) 2015 STMicroelectronics</center></h2>
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
 */

#ifndef STM32F7XX_MCP2515_H_
#define STM32F7XX_MCP2515_H_

#include "stm32f7xx_hal_def.h"

typedef struct
{
    unsigned long IDType; // EID if ide set, SID otherwise
    uint8_t StdFrameRemoteReq; // Standeard Frame Remote Transmit Request
    uint8_t RemoteTxReq; // Remote Transmission Request
    uint8_t ExtIDFlg; // Extended ID Flag
    uint8_t NumDataBytes; // Number of Data Bytes
    uint8_t Data[8]; // Data bytes
} Frame;

/* Make adjustments to the LED Port and Pin location if necessary */
#define USER_LED_PORT           GPIOB
//#define USER_LED_RED          GPIO_PIN_0
#define USER_LED_BLUE           GPIO_PIN_7
//#define USER_LED_GREEN        GPIO_PIN_14

/* SPI Defines */
/* Definition for SPIx Pins */
#define SPI1_GPIO_PORT                   GPIOA
#define SPI1_AF                          GPIO_AF5_SPI1
#define SPI1_SCK_PIN                     GPIO_PIN_5
#define SPI1_MISO_PIN                    GPIO_PIN_6
#define SPI1_MOSI_PIN                    GPIO_PIN_7

/* Definition for Button Pin */
#define SPI1_CS_PIN                      GPIO_PIN_14
#define SPI1_CS_PORT                     GPIOD

/* Definitions of the SPI message sizes*/
#define SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE1               1
#define SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE2               2
#define SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE3               3
#define SPI_MESSAGE_SIZE4               4

#define SPI_TIMEOUT                 0xF000

/* CAN Defines */
// MCP2515 SPI Commands
#define CAN_RESET_BASE          0xC0
#define CAN_RESET               ((uint8_t *)0xC0)
#define CAN_READ_BASE           0x03
#define CAN_READ                ((uint8_t *)0x03)
#define CAN_WRITE_BASE          0x02
#define CAN_WRITE               ((uint8_t *)0x02)
#define CAN_RTS_BASE            0x80
#define CAN_RTS                 ((uint8_t *)0x80)
#define CAN_STATUS_BASE         0xA0
#define CAN_STATUS              ((uint8_t *)0xA0)
#define CAN_BIT_MODIFY_BASE     0x05
#define CAN_BIT_MODIFY          ((uint8_t *)0x05)
#define CAN_RX_STATUS_BASE      0xB0
#define CAN_RX_STATUS           ((uint8_t *)0xB0)
#define CAN_READ_BUFFER_BASE    0x90
#define CAN_READ_BUFFER         ((uint8_t *)0x90)
#define CAN_LOAD_BUFFER_BASE    0X40
#define CAN_LOAD_BUFFER         ((uint8_t *)0X40)

// Register Bit Masks
// CANSTAT
#define MODE_CONFIG         0x80
#define MODE_LISTEN         0x60
#define MODE_LOOPBACK       0x40
#define MODE_SLEEP          0x20
#define MODE_NORMAL         0x00
// CANINTF
#define RX0IF               0x01
#define RX1IF               0x02
#define TX0IF               0x04
#define TX1IF               0x08
#define TX2IF               0x10
#define ERRIF               0x20
#define WAKIF               0x40
#define MERRF               0x80

// Configuration Registers
#define CANSTAT_BASE        0x0E
#define CANSTAT             ((uint8_t *)0x0E)
#define CANCTRL             0x0F
#define BFPCTRL             0x0C
#define TEC                 0x1C
#define REC                 0x1D
#define CNF3                0x28
#define CNF2                0x29
#define CNF1                0x2A
#define CANINTE             0x2B
#define CANINTF             0x2C
#define EFLG                0x2D
#define TXRTSCTRL           0x0D

// TX Buffer 0
#define TXB0CTRL            0x30
#define TXB0SIDH            0x31
#define TXB0SIDL            0x32
#define TXB0EID8            0x33
#define TXB0EID0            0x34
#define TXB0DLC             0x35
#define TXB0D0              0x36
#define TXB0D1              0x37
#define TXB0D2              0x38
#define TXB0D3              0x39
#define TXB0D4              0x3A
#define TXB0D5              0x3B
#define TXB0D6              0x3C
#define TXB0D7              0x3D

// TX Buffer 1
#define TXB1CTRL            0x40
#define TXB1SIDH            0x41
#define TXB1SIDL            0x42
#define TXB1EID8            0x43
#define TXB1EID0            0x44
#define TXB1DLC             0x45
#define TXB1D0              0x46
#define TXB1D1              0x47
#define TXB1D2              0x48
#define TXB1D3              0x49
#define TXB1D4              0x4A
#define TXB1D5              0x4B
#define TXB1D6              0x4C
#define TXB1D7              0x4D

// TX Buffer 2
#define TXB2CTRL            0x50
#define TXB2SIDH            0x51
#define TXB2SIDL            0x52
#define TXB2EID8            0x53
#define TXB2EID0            0x54
#define TXB2DLC             0x55
#define TXB2D0              0x56
#define TXB2D1              0x57
#define TXB2D2              0x58
#define TXB2D3              0x59
#define TXB2D4              0x5A
#define TXB2D5              0x5B
#define TXB2D6              0x5C
#define TXB2D7              0x5D

// RX Buffer 0
#define RXB0CTRL            0x60
#define RXB0SIDH            0x61
#define RXB0SIDL            0x62
#define RXB0EID8            0x63
#define RXB0EID0            0x64
#define RXB0DLC             0x65
#define RXB0D0              0x66
#define RXB0D1              0x67
#define RXB0D2              0x68
#define RXB0D3              0x69
#define RXB0D4              0x6A
#define RXB0D5              0x6B
#define RXB0D6              0x6C
#define RXB0D7              0x6D

// RX Buffer 1
#define RXB1CTRL            0x70
#define RXB1SIDH            0x71
#define RXB1SIDL            0x72
#define RXB1EID8            0x73
#define RXB1EID0            0x74
#define RXB1DLC             0x75
#define RXB1D0              0x76
#define RXB1D1              0x77
#define RXB1D2              0x78
#define RXB1D3              0x79
#define RXB1D4              0x7A
#define RXB1D5              0x7B
#define RXB1D6              0x7C
#define RXB1D7              0x7D

// Buffer Bit Masks
#define RXB0                0x00
#define RXB1                0x02
#define TXB0                0x01
#define TXB1                0x02
#define TXB2                0x04
#define TXB_ALL             TXB0 | TXB1 | TXB2

void MCP2515_GPIO_Configuration();
void MCP2515_SPI_Configuration();

// Initialization function
int MCP2515_Initialise(int baud, uint8_t freq, uint8_t SJW);
int MCP2515_SubInitialise(int baud, uint8_t Freq, uint8_t sjw, uint8_t autoBaud);

// Basic MCP2515 SPI Command Set
void MCP2515_Reset();
uint8_t MCP2515_Read(uint8_t address);
void MCP2515_Read_Multiple(uint8_t address, uint8_t data[], uint8_t bytes);
uint8_t MCP2515_ReadBuffer(uint8_t buffer);
void MCP2515_Single_Write(uint8_t address, uint8_t data);
void MCP2515_LoadBuffer(uint8_t buffer, uint8_t data);
void MCP2515_SendBuffer(uint8_t buffers);
uint8_t MCP2515_Status();
uint8_t MCP2515_RXStatus();
void MCP2515_BitModify(uint8_t address, uint8_t mask, uint8_t data);

// Extra functions
uint8_t MCP2515_Interrupt(); // Expose state of INT pin
uint8_t MCP2515_Mode(uint8_t mode); // Returns TRUE if mode change successful
uint8_t MCP2515_Check_Buffers_Clear(uint8_t info);
uint16_t MCP2515_ReceivingMessage(uint8_t MCP2515_info, uint8_t MCP2515_RXdata);
void MCP2515_SendingMessage(uint8_t MCP2515_info, uint16_t MCP2515_send_long_data, uint8_t MCP2515_send_data);

#endif
```

and main.c

```
void RCC_Configuration(void)
{
    HAL_Init();

    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;

    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType    = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState          = RCC_HSE_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState      = RCC_HSI_OFF;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState      = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource     = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM          = 8;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN          = 256;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP          = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ          = 9;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
    {
        /* Initialization Error */
        while (1) {
        }
    }

    /* Activate the OverDrive to reach the 216 Mhz Frequency */
    if(HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
    {
        while(1) {};
    }

    /* Select PLL as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2
         clocks dividers */
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType       = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource    = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider   = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider  = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider  = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_7) != HAL_OK)
    {
        /* Initialization Error */
        while (1) {
        }
    }

    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
}


int main(void)
{
    RCC_Configuration();
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();

    /* Initialise MCP2515 functions */
    MCP2515_GPIO_Configuration();
    MCP2515_SPI_Configuration();

    if (MCP2515_Initialise(500, 32, 1) == 0) {
        while (1){
        }
    }

    /* Variables in main for MCP2515 */
    uint8_t MCP2515_Info = 0;
    uint8_t MCP2515_SendData = 0xAA;
    uint16_t MCP2515_SendLongData = 0;
    uint16_t MCP2515_ReceivedData = 0;
    uint8_t MCP2515_RXdata;
    while (1)
    {
        MCP2515_Info = MCP2515_Status();
        MCP2515_RXdata = MCP2515_RXStatus();

        // Receiving a Message
        MCP2515_ReceivedData = MCP2515_ReceivingMessage(MCP2515_Info, MCP2515_RXdata);
        // Sending a Message
        MCP2515_SendingMessage(MCP2515_Info, MCP2515_SendLongData, MCP2515_SendData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this post can't be merged with the question directly, because it makes the total length too large. The OP will have to do a better job of condensing his question down to the essential details, rather than dumping entire source files on us.